# Input box and Label in one line Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am Sonal
I am using Modal.And in that I want to create a form in modal.
and in that form i want label and inputBox in one line.
my code is:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#work" style="float:right;font-size:60%;">
        <small> Edit&nbsp;
        </small>
          </a>
          <div class="modal fade " id="work">
        <div class="modal-dialog ">
          <div class="modal-content light">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">work
              </h4>
            </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <fieldset>
                    <label  for="Company">Company Name:
            </label>
                <input type="text" name="Company" id="inputbox" 
                   class="form-control" />
<br>
            <label  for="Job">Job Title:
            </label>
                <input type="text" name="Job" id="inputbox" 
               class="form-control" />
<br>
        </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes
          </button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

this is my modal. my label "company name" and input box in one line.
same with "job title"

Comment: So what's the  question / problem ? Are you saying you are not getting     `input box`  and `label` in one line ?

Comment: Yes But thank you I got the answer

Comment: Great , Then remember to up vote and accept the answers given below .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to know how to layout a form in bootstrap, here you go :

**CODE :**

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Company Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Company Name">
    </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
    <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Job Title:</label>
          </td>
        <td>
          <div class="col-lg-10" style='padding-left:62px;'>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Job Title">
    </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[WORKING DEMO  HERE](http://jsbin.com/OVuzufe/2/edit)

Comment: I want that in one line .It is on left top of the input box.Getting what i want to say?

Comment: @sonal : See my updated answer above. At this stage you are supposed to know how to do this. A little bit of googling won't hurt you. My previous answer was meant to show you , how the `bootstrap` alignment works. The small stuffs like table inline is very easy and you can do that just by adding a table to it. That's not very difficult and you are expected to do it yourself. Don't expect people to give direct answers to your problems. We are here to show you the way. The rest of the path, you have to make yourself.